# Process vector nested within a nested list in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a `list` of `list`s of `vector`s like the following:

```
myList = list(id1 = list(a=6:10,b=1:5),
              id2 = list(a=3:8,b = 4:9))
```

I would like to process the second `vector` named 'b' in each list with an arbitrary `function` (e.g., `mean`, `sum`, etc.) and append the result to a third named `vector` within each nested `list` to achieved something like:

```
myList2 = list(id1 = list(a=6:10,b=1:5,c = mean(1:5)),
          id2 = list(a=3:8,b = 4:9,c = mean(4:9)))
```

Thus, my question has two parts. First, how can I process only the second named `vector` in each nested `list`? Second, how can I append the result to each nested `list`?

I know I can write a `for` loop that always indexes `myList[[i]][[2]]`, but I am looking for a vectorized solution. I've tried using various combinations `apply`-family with an anonymous `function` that first tests the name of the `vector`, for example:

```
rapply(myList, function(x) ifelse(names(x) == "b",
                              print("yes"),  #process vector
                              print("no")),  #move on to next x
   how = "list"
)
```

but the result doesn't make much sense.

Additional information: I'm using nested `list`s instead of a `data.frame` because I don't have the same number of observations for each id, but I am open to alternative approaches that might bypass these issues and accommodate different numbers of observations.

Comment: As an alternative to such a nested "list", you could consider a 'long format' "data.frame" like, e.g., obtained from `dat = do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, id = names(myList), lapply(myList, stack)))` -- then, you could use aggregating operations like `aggregate(values ~ id, dat[dat$ind == "b", ], mean)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
lapply(myList, function(x) {
  x$c <- mean(x$b)
  return(x)
})
```